# Adding a required select box to Jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am using the inline edit option of Jqgrid and want to add a required select box. The first entry should be "please select" and if the user does not choose any other option than "please select" the grid should consider this field as missing and display the build-in "required field is missing" error message.

This is my definition of the select box so far:

```
 {
    name: 'selectbox',
    index: 'selectbox',
    width: 100,
    editable: true,
    required: true,
    edittype: 'select',
    formatter:'select',
    editoptions:{
     value: {1:"Pony", 2:"Ronny"}

}
```

My assumption is that I have to add an option without a value at the beginning of the options block like

```
<option>please select</option>
```

Yet I did not managed to do that and I am not sure if this is the right approach at all.

Comment: have you tried `elementid: {required:true}`

Comment: I have "required: true" in my definition above, but that's probably not what you are meaning?

Comment: okay, then you have to make it in a html, `<select><option value="0">Please Select</option></select>`

Comment: that does not work :-( - "0" is a valid answer for jqgrid and selecting the 0 option does not trigger the required-check.

Comment: then keep just value as `""`

Comment: Ah, yes, that works (tried it with single quotation marks). Do you want to add "{"": "please select", 1:"Pony", 2:"Ronny"}" as answer so that I can upvote it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use `<select><option value=''>Please Select</option></select>`

Comment: for anybody else stumbling along this question: the 'value' construction in the configuration section must look like that: "{"": "please select", 1:"Pony", 2:"Ronny"}"